# Is nimbus.host a valid option in Storm 1.0.2 version?

Tags: apache-storm

There seems to be some conflicting information between [STORM-1185](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-1185) and [STORM-726](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-726).

If we do not want H/A of Nimbus in 1.0.2, is it still ok to use `nimbus.host` (instead of `nimbus.seeds`)? That ways, we can still migrate to 1.0.2 without changing our configuration files which are generated by chef-packs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can leave `nimbus.hosts` there for now. You will get a log message warning that that configuration is deprecated, but things should still work.